# LOCKDOWN_E_PLIST_ERROR when launching on iOSDevice (iPhone 6)

Tags: ios, gradle, javafx, gluon

With: Eclipse Neon, Gluon plug in, Gradle plug in - exporting javaFX to iOS. Exporting from a mac book air mid 2013.

Since: Today, after I installed the new iOS 11 update. It worked 2 weeks ago with the previous version of the OS.

The error **LOCKDOWN_E_PLIST_ERROR** is given in the eclipse console when I *LaunchIOSDevice* - a Gradle task. How come? How can it be solved?

Some background information: After managing to set up eclipse, gluon, and gradle onto my mac (which where necessary to export to iOS javaFX based projects). I had some problems exporting/building it to iOS. I had to increase the max working memory up to 2 gbg by altering the *Eclipse.ini*  - file. I also solved another type of problem (the **Default-Info.plist** file inside the gluonprojects) - Where I had to create a new such file from inside *Xcode* and change the the package name given inside it, and somehow connected to my AppleDeveloper account. Then I replaced the plist file inside the gluonproject and it all worked fine...

Until now, when I have come across this new error that I need help with!

Comment: There is already an issue filed [here](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/issues/172). Once the Mobidevelop version is fixed, the Gluon plugin has to be updated with the new dependency.

Comment: In the meantime, one workaround to get the app installed is using `createIpa` task, and then go to Xcode -> Windows -> Devices, and install the app from there (you will find it under /build/javafxports/ios).

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked! I thought I would have to learn xCode and Swift there for a moment. I had some issues with ram but it worked when I closed down apps that was running and werent used.